# modifications are not supported in cue groups but i have 8 fields in one cue group and i have to divide it into two cue group 4-4 in each

Tags: visual-studio-code, dynamics-365, dynamics-business-central, dynamics-al

I know modifications are not supported in cue groups but i have 8 fields in one cue group and i have to divide it into two cue group 4-4 in each. Is it possible in any way? Please tell.

i am a fresher and i know that this is not supported but i want to know if it is possible in any way. Can we delete the existing page and create a new one . Please tell?